# Unable to resolve service name to its IP inside kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, networking, service, connection, kube-dns

I am able to connect to a service end point by doing 'exec' into any pod of the cluster and then using IP of the service as below:

root@employee-7bbb797cbf-579tr:/usr/apps# curl 10.110.13.105:8080/employee/hello
hello from employee

However, following fails:

root@employee-7bbb797cbf-579tr:/usr/apps# curl employee:8080/employee/hello

it is unable to resolve if the service name is used instead of IP.

What could be missing here?

I verified all recommendations on the official link:
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-debugging-resolution/

All the checks were ok. E.g.
kubectl logs -f -n kube-system coredns-76f75df574-jg9cn
.:53
[INFO] plugin/reload: Running configuration SHA512 = 591cf328cccc12bc490481273e738df59329c62c0b729d94e8b61db9961c2fa5f046dd37f1cf888b953814040d180f52594972691cd6ff41be96639138a43908
CoreDNS-1.11.1
linux/amd64, go1.20.7, ae2bbc2
[INFO] Reloading
[INFO] plugin/reload: Running configuration SHA512 = c0af6acba93e75312d34dc3f6c44bf8573acff497d229202a4a49405ad5d8266c556ca6f83ba0c9e74088593095f714ba5b916d197aa693d6120af8451160b80
[INFO] Reloading complete
[INFO] 127.0.0.1:34979 - 61529 "HINFO IN 4479489531102655118.4960636751153247633. udp 57 false 512" NXDOMAIN qr,rd,ra 132 0.003152382s

Core-dns is in Running state and Calico is CNI being used on kubeadm installation.

The service definition is:
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
name: employee
labels:
app: employee
spec:
type: ClusterIP
ports:

- port: 8080
  targetPort: 8080
  protocol: TCP
  selector:
  app: employee